# Typing predictions on iphone - my language not supported

Tags: iphone, keyboard, language

My language (Slovak) is not among the supported languages for typing predictions on my iphone. Is there any way how I can get it there? An app or some trick? Thank you!

PS: by predictions, I mean that 3 words which come up above the keyboard

Comment: The only thing to do is to see if a 3rd party keyboard from the app store like GBoard might offer it.

Comment: Thank you! Gboard solved the problem!:) btw languages is Slovak